# How to share an EBS volume between 2 or more pods (only one will write, and the rest will only read)?

Tags: kubernetes, race-condition, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, amazon-eks

I understand that `EBS` volumes are currently only `ReadWriteOnce`.

However, I have been able to have a `persistent volume` shared between two or more `pods`, if those `pods` get started almost at the same time. One of them writes to the volumes, and the other one(s) only reads some files.

This approach has not been successful all time: It seems that if for any reason the read-only `pod` gets created ahead of the main `pod`, the main `pod` would get indefinitely stuck at `ContainerCreating` status with `Multi-Attach error for volume ...` warning.

Any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I have successfully tried was to add an `initContainers` to the read-only `pods` with a long `sleep` command there to make sure they do not get created before the main `pod`.